# Method for sharing dynamic dashboard from pandas on shareable file format or html?

Tags: python, pandas, charts

I am working with a large datasets using pandas, which I am perfectly happy with. However, I would like to share simple, main result charts and dashboards with my colleagues and leadership team. The easiest way in our organisation would be a file with all data implemented, like html. I have not found an easy way to do this, which confounds me. Anyone can push me in the right direction or to the right libraries? I find many methods to do similar things to cloud or web, but I'd need to to share as local files.

Anyway to make dynamic charts and output them as a single, dynamic html dashboard, or is there another method to use?

Appreciate the advise,

GregersDK